# Why is a USB 3.0 external hard drive is performing faster than internal hard drives?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, usb, ssd, external-hard-drive

Why is my USB 3.0 connected external hard drive transferring files quicker than my two internal drives? I am using Windows 10.

1. **Internal Primary:** 1TB NVMe Samsung SSD 960 (PCIe Connected)
2. **Internal Storage:** 4TB WDC WD40E31X (SATA Connected)
3. **External Storage:** 2TB USB 3.0 Interface Hard Drive

Now I have a 6.5GB Movie file on my Samsung 960 Pro which I copy to my 4TB WD internal at a rate of 100MB/s

I have the same exact file on my 2TB USB external hard drive which transfers to the same 4TB internal storage Hard Drive at 175MB/s

The same holds true if I try to move 20 large movie files.

Here are some benchmark results from two tools.

#### Performance Test 9:

[image: Performance Test 9]

#### User BenchMark:

[image: User BenchMark]

I had to remove the links for the drives because i don't have enough reputation to add the benchmark results Can someone please add them back

Comment: @JakeGould why is the USB 3.0 External Drive copying files to my 4TB internal drive have a better transfer speed than my 960 SSD to my 4TB Internal. Shouldn't the external drive be slower given the above information.

Comment: Did you run a benchmark tool on the hard drive?

Comment: @SpiderPig Can you recommend a good tool please?

Comment: You could try CrystalDiskMark. Doing the sequential test should be sufficient in this case.

Comment: @SpiderPig i downloaded PerformanceTest9 which is on the PassMark site, i'll update as soon as i get results back :)

Comment: @SpiderPig Uploaded two different benchmarks.

Comment: You could put all the benchmarks into one image. Then you only need one link. You only need to use one benchmark software. But test all the drives involved.

Comment: is your internal drive doing other things you're not aware of that's slowing it down? Running programs or being used as a page file? Check task manager

Comment: When you copy a file and want to measure the transfer speed you need to wait a few seconds until the speed has stabilized. The initial speed is due to buffering in ram.

Comment: @SpiderPig i know, the speeds i mentioned above are the average speed for the 10 minute transfer. Also it would still be 3 links and it wouldn't let me since i lack the reputation.

Comment: @Blaine That was my first thought as well, no there isn't any activity on the drive. I started windows without any 3rd party services running or startup items. Is a 100 MB/s transfer rate normal or should it be higher for NAND SSD to storage media?

Comment: 100 MB/s is normal for a hard disk. And it would be only 1 link since you can combine as many images into one as you want. Even with a very simple program like windows paint.

Comment: @SpiderPig what i'm saying is, yes it would be 1 link for the images but still 2 links for the two hard drives, for 3 links total. I can't have more than 2 links due to low reputation haha.

Comment: @JordanGS No idea, but it should not be lower than to an external drive. Unless... Is your built in drive on Sata, or still using the old IDE interface?

Comment: @Blaine it's SATA, built it myself. I'm rather stumped on it myself.